# Getting different results of fullscreen mode in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, css

My original application is not viewing correctly (in all browsers) in fullscreen mode, which is OpenLayers 3 functionality. The problem is with that map  does not cover all of my screen and it still displays my header/sidebar/footer (but only with one color).

I have everyting positioned absolutely:

```
#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 300px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
} ... etc for sidebar, footer...
```

ONLY FIREFOX fullscreen mode displays everything correctly, Chrome and explorer are not OK.

Is this the question of CSS?

Is this the question of fullscreen javascript API in browsers?

Is this Openlayers fullscreen mode bug?

There is an example of original application in windowed mode.

Firefox - version 34.0

[image: windowed]

There is an example of fullscreen in Internet explorer.

Internet explorer - version 11.0.9600.17416

[image: explorer fullscreen]

and last is Google Chrome - Version 39.0.2171.71 m
[image: chrome fullscreen]

Comment: what if you remove left, right and top coordinates from the #map?

Comment: It doesnt result in correct fullscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same issue in Google Chrome. Everything works correctly in Mozilla or IE. Here is my CSS definition of the div where the map is loading.

```
.map {
height: 35em;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0.2em solid #209CA6;
}
```

When I go full screen this happens:
[image]

I realized that reason why this is happening is the fixed setting of the height of the div. The height is set to 35em. When I change the height to 100% like this:

```
.map {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0.2em solid #209CA6;
}
```

It works just fine:
[image]

However I wanted to keep my map the fixed height of 35em. In that case I used following code and it works perfectly:

```
.map:-webkit-full-screen {
   height: 100%;
 }
 .map:-moz-full-screen {
   height: 100%;
 }
 .map:-ms-fullscreen {
   height: 100%;
 }
 .map:fullscreen {
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I updated Firefox to version 35.0.1 and suddenly fullscreen functionality works again (IE + Chrome dont)! So as I suspected this error is related to version of every internet browser and javascript fullscreen api.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with Chrome, i solved wrapping the map in another div:

```
#map-home {  
  height:100%;
  width:100%;    
}
.map-wrap{    
  height:300px;
  width: 100%;        
}
<div class="map-wrap">
  <div id="mymap" class=""></div>
</div>
```

Now it works on FF and Chrome and Edge.